# How to expand a column with an accumulated sequence of its delimited values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I would like to expand/repeat # of rows based on the length of sequences. For example:

```
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.DataFrame({"id":[11,12], "seq":['A,B,C', 'A,B,C,D'], "y":[1, 5]})
print(df)

   id      seq  y
0  11    A,B,C  1
1  12  A,B,C,D  5
```

I would this df to be

```
   id      seq     y
0  11      A       1
1  11      A,B     1
2  11      A,B,C   1
3  12      A       5
4  12      A,B     5
5  12      A,B,C   5
6  12      A,B,C,D 5
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: `df['seq'] = df['seq'].str.split(',')`                `df.explode('seq')`

Comment: I think that would only create `seq` with `A` and `B` and `C` rather than the sublists which OP seems to want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could collect the odd-length prefixes of each `seq` string in a list comprehension and then explode the dataframe on those lists:

```py
df['seq'] = df.seq.apply(lambda s: [s[:i] for i in range(1, len(s)+1, 2)])
df = df.explode('seq')
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
    id  seq      y
0   11  A        1
1   11  A,B      1
2   11  A,B,C    1
3   12  A        5
4   12  A,B      5
5   12  A,B,C    5
6   12  A,B,C,D  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to use [`groupby expanding`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.expanding.html) after [`explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html):

```
df['seq'] = df['seq'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('seq')
df['seq'] = [','.join(ewv) for ewv in df.groupby(level=0).expanding()['seq']]
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

`df`:

```
   id      seq  y
0  11        A  1
1  11      A,B  1
2  11    A,B,C  1
3  12        A  5
4  12      A,B  5
5  12    A,B,C  5
6  12  A,B,C,D  5
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming a unique index (or a unique ID in a given column), and since you need to loop anyway, you could avoid using `explode`  by directly creating the correct output column and expanding the original dataframe with [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) (or [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) if using a column as ID):

```
s = pd.Series(*zip(*((','.join(l[:i+1]), idx)
                     for idx, l in zip(df.index, df['seq'].str.split(','))
                     for i in range(len(l)))),
             name='seq')

out = df.drop(columns='seq').join(s)[df. columns]
```

Alternatively, a step by step method to construct `s`:

```
# split strings
tmp = df['seq'].str.split(',')
# construct the incremental strings
vals = [','.join(l[:i+1])
        for l in tmp
        for i in range(len(l))]

# convert to Series
s = pd.Series(vals, index=df.index.repeat(tmp.str.len()),
              name='seq')

# join
out = df.drop(columns='seq').join(s)[df. columns]
```

Output:

```
   id      seq  y
0  11        A  1
0  11      A,B  1
0  11    A,B,C  1
1  12        A  5
1  12      A,B  5
1  12    A,B,C  5
1  12  A,B,C,D  5
```

Intermediate `s`:

```
0          A
0        A,B
0      A,B,C
1          A
1        A,B
1      A,B,C
1    A,B,C,D
Name: seq, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

First, splitting and exploding to get new rows:

```
df['seq1'] = df['seq'].str.split(',')
df = df.explode('seq1')
```

Then in groups, for each sequence, do a cumulative appending of the values. Then split and join them while stripping the leading and trailing commas that appear due to that split.

```
df['l'] = df.groupby('id')['seq1'].apply(
    lambda s: s.cumsum().str.split('').str.join(',').str.strip(','))
```

Thus,

```
>>> df
   id      seq  y seq1        l
0  11    A,B,C  1    A        A
0  11    A,B,C  1    B      A,B
0  11    A,B,C  1    C    A,B,C
1  12  A,B,C,D  5    A        A
1  12  A,B,C,D  5    B      A,B
1  12  A,B,C,D  5    C    A,B,C
1  12  A,B,C,D  5    D  A,B,C,D
```