# Expand Pandas DataFrame with numerical values?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to expand my DataFrame and I have checked out a similar [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68354526/how-to-repeat-expand-pandas-data-frame) on stackoverflow but without any success. Any idea how to fix it?

This is my toy example

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

id = [100, 101]
nums = ['9, 5', '11, 12, 13']
out = [1, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'nums':nums, 'y':out})
df

    id  nums        y
0   100 9, 5        1
1   101 11, 12, 13  0
```

I use the similar the code with that example as before

```
# explode nums into a sequential order
df['nums'] = ["".join(i.split()) for i in df['nums']]
df['nums'] = df['nums'].apply(lambda s: [s[:i] for i in range(1, len(s)+1, 2)])
df = df.explode('nums')           
df.reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

but this is what I got  (the last 4 rows are wrong)

```
    id  nums    y
0   100 9       1
0   100 9,5     1
1   101 1       0
1   101 11,     0
1   101 11,12   0
1   101 11,12,1 0
```

The CORRECT one should be like following:

```
    id  nums      y
0   100 9         1
0   100 9,5       1
1   101 11        0
1   101 11,12     0
1   101 11,12,13  0
```

any idea? many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't need that extra `"".join` if you want to just deal with the number values.
2. Your offsets for the `apply` are a bit off.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': id, 'nums':nums, 'y':out})
    id        nums  y
0  100        9, 5  1
1  101  11, 12, 13  0
>>> df["nums"] = df["nums"].str.split(", ").apply(lambda s: [s[:i] for i in range(1, len(s) + 1, 1)])
>>> df.explode("nums")
    id          nums  y
0  100           [9]  1
0  100        [9, 5]  1
1  101          [11]  0
1  101      [11, 12]  0
1  101  [11, 12, 13]  0
>>>
```

If you need `nums` to be a string again, you can now `.join` it again.